# How can i share image from my web application to Instagram?

Tags: reactjs

I have create one application in React-js for edit images after editing image i want to share(post) that image in Instagram how can i do that?
How can i use Instagram developer API to post the images from my application to Instagram so that user can directly post the image that he has edited in my application.
please give me steps if it's possible because i am performing integration first time.

Comment: Hi Jagruti, were you able to post images on instagra? If so, can you add your answer here? I am in a similar situation

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start when implementing a third-party API is the docs!
https://www.instagram.com/developer/

But there are other great resources/tutorials online as well.
Here is a Medium article on building an Instagram embedded App with Expo and React Native. 
https://hackernoon.com/build-an-instagram-feed-app-with-just-javascript-using-expo-react-native-97c0e799b5cf

Comment: Tanks for response.